# How to return a reference to an object created conditionally in Rust?

Tags: rust, conditional-statements, lifetime

I have a fairly rookie Rust question, but I can't figure it out. In short, I have a situation where I want to return a struct instance from a conditional block, but the struct contains a reference to an object that also gets created in that block. For example, something like:

```rs
struct Foo<'a> {
    num: &'a u8,
}

let fooOpt = if true {
    let num = 4;
    Some(Foo {
        num: &num,
    })
} else {
    None
};
```

This doesn't work, because the returned `Foo` contains a reference to `num`, which is dropped at the end of the `if` block. What is the right way to do this? I tried some hijinks with the struct taking ownership of `num` (in the real code it's an object instead of a `u8`, and the reference is to something inside the object), but structs containing references to data owned by themselves is [surprisingly hard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html#example-self-referential-struct). Is there some simple way to do this that I'm just missing?

Comment: It's hard to give a suggestion without a real-world example. If shared ownership is appropriate, there's `Arc`/`Rc`.

Comment: No, you're not missing something. Self-referential structs are indeed a hard problem in Rust. The usual answer is "don't use them". I realize that doesn't solve every use case, but it might solve yours. Can you explain a bit more what your actual use case looks like? Perhaps we can offer an alternative.

Comment: Can you declare the variable outside the block?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo The real code is an [`rusqlite::Connection`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/latest/rusqlite/struct.Connection.html) that I'm calling [`.prepare()`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/latest/rusqlite/struct.Connection.html#method.prepare) on to make an [`rusqlite::Statement`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/latest/rusqlite/struct.Statement.html). I really only care about the `Statement`, but it keeps a reference to the `Connection` so that needs to stay alive, and I only use the database in certain conditions so I'm actually passing around an `Option<rusqlite::Statement>`

Comment: @MichaelMrozek That one is really hard. The `.prepare()` borrows the `Connection` to create the `Statement`. That indicates that they really don't intent to put those in the same object together. I think you should store the `Connection` outside, somewhere and pass it around. There isn't really another way to solve this without `unsafe` and `Pin`. Even `Arc`/`Rc` wouldn't help you there, because the Rust compiler has no idea that you keep the object alive with the `Rc`. So by far the best advice is to change your program layout to avoid the problem in the first place.

Comment: I agree with Finomnis. It sounds like you want `Connection` to be a value declared higher up in your program as a local variable (maybe even in `main`, depending on needs), and then have whatever functions need it take a reference (mutable, if needed by your library) to that connection object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self Referential structs are very hard. If you aren't sure you have to use them, you don't.
In your case, if you can declare the objects outside the conditional, that would be ideal.

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    num: &'a u8,
}
let num = 4;
let fooOpt = if true {
    Some(Foo {
        num: &num,
    })
} else {
    None
};
```

I understand that this is probably a smaller example. If the object is very big or time consuming to create, then you can just declare it and leave the construction for later.

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    num: &'a u8,
}
let num;
let fooOpt = if true {
    num = 4;
    Some(Foo {
        num: &num,
    })
} else {
    None
};
```

This will only initialise the `num` variable when it is used, but the variable itself would be in the outer scope and thus, borrowing it would be fine.

Comment: I do need to avoid initializing it unless the condition is true, but the second example accomplishes that so it might be what I end up doing; for some reason I just didn't think of declaring it outside but not initializing it. It annoys me that I'm forced to leak `num` into the outer scope to make it work, especially a `num` that might not even be initialized, but that's the way it goes.

Comment: "for some reason I just didn't think of declaring it outside but not initializing it" TBF it's pretty non-intuitive as it's very alien to most languages, but in Rust it's *extremely* convenient once you get told about it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek you aren't really leaking an unintialised variable. If you try to use it when it isn't initialised, that's a compilation error. So you wouldn't face any problems with using an unitialised variable. You also wouldn't be able to assign to it outside the branch because `num` must only be initialised once and it might have been initialised already in the `if` branch. So, basically, declaration-with-initialization might not look pretty but it is pretty safe in rust.